# Boot loader loaded in board. Board getting stuck while booting at different places during each re-start

Tags: linux, u-boot

I flashed u-boot and linux in my custom board based on ARM9 based SoC(KSZ9692PBI from micrel). Board has 8MB NOR flash,64MB DDR. I am facing the following issues

1. 75% of times u-boot is loading succesfully and starts linux, but linux booting sometimes hangs at starting itself and othercases hangs in between.
2. 25 % of times u-boot itself hangs at different places.

DDR frequency 200MHZ,CPU at 250MHz.

I think there is no loose connection in the board.

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Have you tried `mtest`? It sounds like RAM issues, possibly tuning for the board.

Comment: I am also doubting DDR issue...But am bit confused. Because u-boot and kernel is able to boot to some extent means DDR is working...What makes the DDR failure or improper behaviour randomly at various locations? I am doubting SI issue, power supply fluctuation, decoupling issues etc. Reducing DDR frequency will help?

Comment: I worked with a custom board with DDR3, based off of the schematic of a reference board. Originally, I left the DDR tuning as programmed for the original board and I had some units that exhibited similar symptoms to what you are seeing. It turned out that the trace layout was different enough that the memory controller programming needed to be changed. We worked with the CPU vendor to obtain a tool for determining the correct tuning and this fixed the problem. Reducing the frequency may help. DDR timing is will past me so I am not sure.

Comment: *"I am also doubting DDR issue."*  -- You don't have a convincing argument for your assumptions. *"I think there is no loose connection in the board."* is a lame analysis of your hardware.  Until you have run extensive tests of every RAM location with stress patterns, you cannot rule out memory issues.  The **mtest** command in U-Boot is a quick way to get some results.

Comment: @DoxyLover My board is also a custom board based on a reference design. DDR signal layout is different from reference board and i am using the u-boot of the reference board. There are 44 registers for tuning the DDR. I dont know how to change it. I will ask the vendor. My vendor is Micrel

Comment: @user3856305 - good luck. By the way, one more thing we observed was extreme temperature sensitivity in the DDR chips. Although the chips were not warm to the touch, spraying them with freeze spray would make the board work perfectly, as long as the DDR was kept cold, allowing them to warm up again would cause the board to fail. My understanding is that the temperature was changing the timing of the chips enough to make it work.

Comment: @user3856305 -- You have a custom board.  Therefore you need a memory diagnostic/exerciser.  Using "boot Linux kernel" as a diagnostic is foolish.  I was doing development on a board with a faulty memory layout.  Five out of 8 boards seemed to work reliably, but 3 boards would exhibit random kernel panics or rare boot failures.  Only a memory diagnostic would prove that the HW design was flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though we don't know for sure that this is the OP's problem, I've decided to elevate my comments to an answer to better preserve it.

I've worked on a custom board with an ARM9 SOC and DDR3 chips. It was laid out from the manufacturer's reference board schematic and I was initially running it with the same memory controller configuration as the reference board. Most boards worked correctly but some showed similar symptoms to what you are seeing.

During debug, we noted that even though the DDR chips were not warm to the touch, cooling them with freeze spray would make the board work correctly. As long as the DDR was kept cool, the board would run `mtest` indefinitely, and even boot into Linux and continue running. If we allowed the chips to warm back up, the board would hang.

Our hardware guys decided that it must be timing and the cooling was changing the chip timing enough to make the memory controller configuration work. We contacted our vendor (Marvell) and they provided a tool which ran through the JTAG pod to center the timing and provide the proper controller configuration.

This solved the problem on all failing boards.

Comment: I changed the DDR configuration from 32 bit to 16 bit. Now the board is starting consistently and getting hanged at mounting ramfs stage. I need to debug the issue. But random hanging problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DDR frequency to 166 resolved the issue...It is definitely the timing issue at 200 MHz...